# How to save backend execution state and resume it later?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, backend, .net-standard

I have a .NET Core application that communicates with the angular front end through some web APIs.
There's one part of the application that needs to wait for some user input before it can continue with its work, something like this:

[image: frontend backend interactoin]

Because of some technical problems which cannot be avoided, in order to implement this concept, the only possible solution that I could think of is to somehow serialize the internal state (everything including the state of the locally scoped variables), save the point of execution, store this information somewhere and then, after the user input, finally restore all the data and continue the execution from where it left off.

Is this possible to do? How would you proceed to implement it?

Comment: You can use a BackGroundWorker and then have an event when work is completed.

Comment: "The only possible solution that I could think of is to somehow serialize the internal state and point of execution, save it somewhere and restore it after the user input, to continue from where it left.".   And what is the exact question ? Because this statement (almost) proofs that you know how to solve this problem.

Comment: BTW: "2. Is there any other approach that is more suitable for this problem?" Is a reason to close this question, because it asks for an opinion...

Comment: @Luuk That's the conceptual approach but I'm not sure if that's really possible to implement. I tried looking around but still couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: You question is very broad, and is hard to answer 'in general', because of statements like "because the logic can't be separated that way" and "Calling just another method after the waiting period will result in some missing logic."   Maybe you should give more details about what your real problem.

Comment: Ok, I've changed the description a bit and focused just on one point.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, TaskCompletionSource<bool>> taskCompletionSources = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, TaskCompletionSource<bool>>();

public IActionResult StartExecution(...)
{
    ...
    Operation(...); // Non-blocking call
    ...
}

private async Task Operation(...)
{
    if(condition) {
        if(condition) {
            //[wait for input]
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>(TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning | TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously); // bool or whatever the user response will give us
            var uid = // generate some unique id (like Guid.NewGuid())
            taskCompletionSources.TryAdd(uid, tcs);
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
            // Now we notify client to update UI with something like SignalR  //
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
            var userChoice = await tcs.Task; // Wait until user answers (FinishJob will give us the user choice)
            taskCompletionSources.TryRemove(uid, out tcs);
            ...execute some logic...
        }
        ...execute some logic...
    }
    ...execute some logic...
}

public IActionResult FinishJob(string uid, bool yesNo)
{
    if(taskCompletionSources.TryGetValue(uid, out var tcs))
        tcs.SetResult(yesNo); // This will unblock the await in Operation()
}
```

So basically when the user press Start Button, it performs a call to StartExecution.

StartExecution fires and forget Operation.

Operation does its work until it needs to update the UI.
So it creates a TaskCompletionSource that will await. Its result will be set when the user click Continue
It does this with SignalR sending also the generated uid.

The UI updates and stores the uid, then wait for the user to press Continue.

When the user press Continue, it performs a call to FinishJob passing the uid and true if the user want to continue the job.

FinishJob set the result of the previously instantiated TaskCompletionSource